# Microsoft Access 2010+ user rights

Tags: ms-access

With Access 2007 Microsoft stopped security on userlevel. Does anyone know a possibility to give user permissions?

Only trusted user have access to my database. Nevertheless, there are too many and they WILL accidentally damage the data structure, like deleting or more 'evil' editing a primary key of the main table, or something similar.

(I do not need any safety against hacking)

The problem is, I can't simply run a SQL Server. The users are in a private network, the file is on a secure private network drive, and they do not have administrative rights on their computers to install additional software, so the solution has to be done with windows and access 2010+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access 2007 and later still support user-level security for databases in the older MDB format.  If your application doesn't require features only available in the newer ACCDB formats, you can use a shared MDB for data storage and the users could each have their own copy of a front-end db which links to the shared  MDB tables.

If that is not satisfactory, "compile" your ACCDB to an ACCDE version and then rename the ACCDE to ACCDR.  The ACCDR can then only be opened in runtime mode, which restricts the operations available to your users.  Basically you can allow them to interact with the database only with forms you provide --- so you can control what they can do.

Comment: Thanks! The compiled Accdr solution will be sufficient against accidents :)

Comment: Good.  A sneaky user could rename the ACCDR back to ACCDE which would allow them more freedom.  Since it seems your concern is safeguarding against accidents, that is probably not a concern.  I mentioned that point as a warning for other readers.